# How do i retrieve the earlier date of a column and merge duplicates of the a different column together?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, duplicates

I have this table:

```
CUSTOMER NAME   JOINED DATE
Daniel          03/01/2013
Daniel          04/01/2013
Daniel          23/05/2013
Zack            27/06/2013
Zack            06/08/2013
Patricia        07/01/2015
John            08/05/2008
John            02/05/2013
John            23/05/2013
John            08/06/2015
Stephanie       16/04/2010
Stephanie       08/05/2012
Stephanie       28/09/2012
Stephanie       23/01/2013
Stephanie       28/03/2014
Elizabeth       18/04/2013
Elizabeth       22/04/2013
Elizabeth       25/04/2013
```

And I've looked and can't figure out how to return a query that removes the duplicates in [Customer Name] column but keeps the earliest date in the [Joined date] column belonging to the [customer name], see below for desired output:

`customer name  Joined on`

`Daniel         03/01/2013
 Zack           27/06/2013
 Patricia       07/01/2015
 John           08/05/2008
 Stephanie      16/04/2010
 Elizabeth      18/04/2013`

I am new to sql and coding in general, I read somewhere that you can use a MIN(DATE) statment? or a case when statement to find this? but i'm still not sure:

`select distinct [customer name], [joined date] from database.dbo.practise  where [status ] = 'live'
  and [joined date] = (select min(joined date) from database.dbo.practise)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT [CUSTOMER NAME], MIN([joined date]) AS "Joined on"
FROM database.dbo.practise
GROUP BY [CUSTOMER NAME]
```